# Access page template on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I need to access a page template in a wordpress site to edit a spacing issue.
Is there anyway to do this through the interface or do I need to find the file on the web server?

Answer (score 1):

Go to menu `"Appearance" -> "Editor"` (You should log in as Admin) and find your page template in right sidebar. Your can edit it here from panel if template file has these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

a page template has to be found in the theme folder of the theme you are using.

It should be named something similar to the template name of the page. You should be able to find it having the Page Template comment tags having its name on the top of the file.

As defined here, http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

Hope it helps